# How to answer a question related to my plan upon completion of internship given my circumstances?

Tags: interviewing, career-development, internship

I am a new grad, and I'm offered an interview for internship by one of my dream companies related to Artificial Intelligence and Machine Learning.

The reason why I applied for internship is that I'm going back to academia next Fall. My plan for this year is to get summer internship, and to go back to school for graduate studies.

However, I didn't expect to get an interview offer from my dream company, and this makes me feel uncertain about my career goals. If I work really hard and my internship ends with a full-time job offer (I wish), *I would be happy to accept an offer and stay in the industry for a couple years before I go to graduate schools*.

But if the interviewer asks what would be my plan upon the completion of internship, how should I properly answer this question? Should I not mention about graduate studies at all?

Comment: Do you know for sure they will/can give you a full time job offer after the internship? I know it is usually that way, but have they mentioned anything explicitly about the option to stay?

Comment: I haven't had an interview yet but I I'll ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if the interviewer asks what would be my plan upon the completion of internship, how should I properly answer this question? Should I not mention about graduate studies at all?

I think you should be honest and tell them about your studies (as that shows interest in learning), but that doesn't mean you are closing the doors for a full-time offer by saying that.

Something worth noticing is the assumption that they will ask you that. There is a chance that they don't ask this at all. Or, that they phrase the question in other way were you can easily expose to them your plans (stay full-time else go back to study).

Who knows, in the ideal case they could even ask you *"If given the chance to stay with us after the internship, would you take it?"*...

So...Perhaps, an answer I would suggest **if** prompted with that exact question you say would be:

> Recruiter: *So what are your plans after completing the internship?*
>
> Ted: *Well, if given the chance to stay here I would take it. Otherwise, I would like to continue my studies in [...]*

That way you are exposing your interest in staying if given the opportunity, and are also being honest with your intentions of continuing your studies.